# Cannot hash password with bcrypt

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, bcrypt

I've been trying to implement bcrypt within my user so I can use JWT for authentication; however whenever I try to hash my password with bcrypt it throws and error in the first if statement. I am using the express.js as my framework. I also have to mention that I am not using a database and the user is stored within an array in a different file. I am new to node and I'm still trying to understand it.

My user routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const users = require('../../Users');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        } else {
            const user = {
                id: users.length + 1,
                userName: req.body.userName,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hash,
                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                lastName: req.body.lastName,
            }
            user
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result)
                    res.status(201).json({
                        message: 'User created'
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).json({
                        error: err
                    });
                })
        }
    })
})
```

Client request

```
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "testerpassword",
    "userName": "test",
    "firstName": "teste",
    "lastName": "tester"
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using passport. it would be better / easier to use passport and a strategy which does everything for you.

Comment: Haven't looked into passport, I will give it a try.

Comment: solution would be to use a tested and proved framework instead of building your own. examples are on the site.

Comment: @jcuypers I don't think I can use passport as I am not using a database.

Comment: @razvanusc ok, you are not error check input or nothing.  try to replace the req.body.password with a fixed string value and see if the error goes away or moves. or just try to console log the value before trying.  we need to make sure the value is defined.

Comment: When I set a fixed value it gives me the following error: `/Users/razvanusc/code/razvanusc/project-tool/routes/api/users.js:22
                .then()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188952/discussion-between-jcuypers-and-razvanusc).

Answer (score 0):

Make a helper method that takes the password and returns and encrypted one:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const hashThePassword = (str) => {
  if (typeof str == "string" && str.length > 0) {
    const hash = crypto
      .createHmac("sha256", config.hashingSecret)
      .update(str)
      .digest("hex");
    return hash;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

The config object contains an arbitrary secret string.