# Problem hashing password with bcrypt on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, bcrypt

I have the code below. I'm trying to hash my admin password when they get registered. The password initially is set to default via the mongoose schema. Below are my codes. But it is not hashing.

```
 AdminSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  let admin = this; // bind this

  if(admin.$isDefault('password')) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(12, (err, salt)=> { // generate salt and harsh password
            bcrypt.hash(admin.password, salt, (err, hash)=> {
                admin.password = hash;
                return next();
            });
        });
    }

    if(!admin.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }

    bcrypt.genSalt(12, (err, salt)=> { // generate salt and harsh password
        bcrypt.hash(admin.password, salt, (err, hash)=> {
            admin.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but there was a similar quetion (+answer) just recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851280/cannot-hash-password-with-bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

It's because bcrypt method are execute asynchronously so for the first time this will be always executed

```
if(!admin.isModified('password')) {
  return next();
}
```

this should work

```
AdminSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const admin = this // bind this

  if (admin.$isDefault('password') || admin.isModified('password')) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(12, (err, salt) => { // generate salt and harsh password
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      bcrypt.hash(admin.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        admin.password = hash
        return next()
      })
    }) 
  } else {
    return next();
  }
})
```

Comment: It works but when I update the password, it will not hash. This is the problem I have been having. I use bcryptjs.

Comment: Are you sure this 'admin.isModified('password')' return true when the password is modified ?

Comment: How do you update the password ? And how are you saving the model at the end of the request

Comment: This is my update code:

Admin.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set:body}, {new: true}).then((doc)=>{
        // check if doc was foun and updated
        if(!doc){
            res.status(404).send();
        }

        res.send(doc);

        // Admin.findById(id).then(doc=>{
        //     res.send(doc);
        // })
        
        }).catch((e)=>{
            res.status(400).send();
        });
        // return the updated doc
    });

Comment: Oh ok that's the problem the method 'findByIdAndUpdate' don't call the prev save event. You need to fetch the model, modify the value and save it

Comment: Sir I simply updated findByIdAndUpdate method to findOneAndUpdate because mongoose was complaining that the former was deprecated and your code works well.

Thanks sir.

Comment: Just to add to it. I actually remove bcryptjs and used bcrypt instead.